# Proportional edit with a given target position by script?

Tags: mesh

Is there a way to go from here:
[image: Mesh with some selected vertices]

to here:

[image: Selected vertices raised to Z = 0, with proportional edit]
...using a script?

Trying to be clear: I have a mesh (possibly very big) with some vertices selected. I want to write a script that brings all selected vertices up to the same level (Z = 0). The catch is that I want to do it with proportional edit so that nearby vertices are also raised a bit (not illustrated in the images).

Since the selected vertices are all on different Z at the start I can't just do a translation (with proportinal edit activated). On the other hand, if I just set the Z coordinate to 0 I wouldn't get proportional editing at all. If I translate them one by one with proportional edit I would still end up with some of them higher than 0 (since nearby vertices would mutually raise each other a bit extra).

Maybe I could solve it with cloth simulation or something but it would be tough to do on a big scale.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried the scale (resize) operator to 0 with proportional edit activated? https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.transform.html#bpy.ops.transform.resize

Comment: Thanks! Scale operator was the missing piece. Now it seems so obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple operation that shouldn't require a script, but if you need a script for it, please let me know. The steps are as follows.

1. Activate proportional editing.
2. Switch the *Transform Pivot Point* to **3D Cursor**.
3. Center the 3D cursor by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
4. Select the vertices you want to affect.
5. Scale to zero along the z-axis by pressing <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>Z</kbd> > <kbd>0</kbd>.
6. Scroll the mouse wheel to increase or decrease the affected area around the selected vertices.

I attached two screenshots to help illustrate this.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

---

**Edit:** The following is a script to achieve the same results as the steps above. It's simpler, because most of the setup can be achieved by passing parameters to the operator.

```py
import bpy

# The parameters were exposed here to make it easier to customize the results.
# The scale components set to 1.0 will prevent the selected points from moving along the respective axes. Since we only want the z position of the selected points to move, we set the z-component of the scale to zero (in addition to customizing the center as shown below).
scale = (1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
# falloff and proportional_size determine how the neighboring vertices will move.
falloff = 'SMOOTH'
proportional_size = 3.0
# The center of scaling determines where the selected points will end up when scaled to zero. The x and y-components will not have any effect as we set the scale components along those axes to 1.0.
center = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

# Store current mode
mode = bpy.context.active_object.mode

# Switch to edit mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

# Perform the scaling operation using the parameters
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=scale, 
                         orient_type='LOCAL', 
                         use_proportional_edit=True, 
                         proportional_edit_falloff=falloff, 
                         proportional_size=proportional_size, 
                         center_override=center)

# Restore mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=mode)
```

Comment: Scale to Z 0. Of course. Why didn't I think of that? Yes, it has to be a script. Can all these steps be done via script? I guess they can.

Comment: I added the script to the answer.